# Populate array as per result of parent array

Tags: php, database, arrays

I have a parent array that contains
years as 
`1994,
1995,
1996,
1997,
1998,
1999,
2000,
2005`

and on the other hand i am getting result from my db that returns year and count , Now, what i am trying to do is that an array being populated as per parent array (years) for the results being generated for something like following:

```
Results being Generated by sql
+----------------+
 YEAR   |   Count
 1994   |    16
 1995   |    16
 1996   |    16
+----------------+
```

The array should store following values as per check if sql query results contains result for year of parent array or not

```
1994   |    16
1995   |    16
1996   |    16
1997   |    0
1998   |    0
1999   |    0
2000   |    0
2005   |    0
```

Thanks,
Note I want the reuslt to be generated in an array as mentioned above because i have to pass these values to highcharts (For generating graph)

Comment: Post some code please so we know the current variable names that you use

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends how `$years_db` is built, Here an example:

```
$years       = array(1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2000, 2005);
$years_db    = array(1994 => 16, 1995 => 16, 1996 => 16);

$array_temp = array();
foreach ($years as $year)
{
    /* if (in_array($year, array_keys($years_db)))
     * $array_temp[$year] = $years_db[$year];
     * else
     * $array_temp[$year] = 0;
     */

    // @gumbo suggestion is more efficient. THX!
    $array_temp[$year] = isset($years_db[$year]) ? $years_db[$year] : 0;
}

output of $array_temp:
array (
  1994 => 16,
  1995 => 16,
  1996 => 16,
  1997 => 0,
  1998 => 0,
  1999 => 0,
  2000 => 0,
  2005 => 0,
)
```

Comment: Better use `array_key_exists($year, $years_db)` or `isset($years_db[$year])` instead of `in_array($year, array_keys($years_db))`.